# Call a function in main from a module

Tags: perl

I'm using a module which call functions from my main script.

The following code is used to run functions :

```
&{$function}();
```

Where $function is simply the name of the called function.

The problem is that the function must be in the same module.

I'd like to call functions from my main script.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Does such code even compiles? I mean - `use strict;` should make it impossible, and you are using strict mode, right?

Comment: Sounds like a back-to-front design really, calling functions in a script from a module...

Comment: you mean it's a bad idea ? This module is a small timer lib. tried to use better implementations, but was to complicated to my usage

Answer (score 3):

```
sub call_function {
  my $name = shift;
  my $caller = caller;

  no strict 'refs';
  my $output = &{ $caller . "::" . $name }();
}
```

We need to call the sub by the fully qualified name. If the sub doesn't originate in our package, we need to prefix it with the correct package name. The `caller` builtin comes in handy for this: it returns the name of the package where our sub was called from.

Comment: While technically working, I wouldn't say it's good solution. Disabling strict, depending on specific name of a function. Sending CODEREF is cleaner and more powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume in your main program you have:

```
use Some::Module;

sub whatever { ... }

Some::Module::function(1,2,3);
```

And in the `function` you want to call whatever() sub.

You can change the function to take one more argument, which will be reference to the `whatever` function. And then:

In your main program:

```
Some::Module::function(1,2,3,\&whatever);
```

and in the Some::Module:

```
sub function {
    my ($x, $y, $z, $more_work) = @_;
    ...
    $more_work->();
}
```